# SAS Raid Controller

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I am working with a sys admin on a DELL PowerEdge 710.  The sysadmin purchased the server before I was advised with no cache on the raid controller, we are running a SQL server and needed to have cache on the raid controller.  The server only has 6 slots, originally all 6 were on the raid controller with no cache.  We moved two to the new cached controller but were reluctant, the server works fin but there is an error on start up because the orginal card is looking for the two drives.

E1A15 SAS cable B not found (the original controller is throwing this error)

How do I reset this error > ?

Comment: Find a competent SysAdmin to advise on the situation... You almost certainly want to move the rest of the drives to the cached controller and properly configure the array(s) on it (or both if it's necessary to keep the zero cache controller in the box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don`t you ask Dell?
Or was the server bought without hardware support?

I would go the the original raid-controller, unsetup the raids there, go to the bios and disable the old raid controller.